# Share nfs volume between kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

We have the setup in GKE with two different clusters. One cluster is running a nfs-server and on that cluster we have a persistent-volume which points to the server. This PV is then mounted on a pod running on this cluster. The second cluster also has a PV and a pod that should mount the same nfs volume. Here is where the problem occurs. Where we point out the server it does not work with using the nfs-server clusterIp address. This is understandable but I wonder how to best achieve this.

The setup is basically this:

Persistent Volume and Persistent Volume Claim used by NFS

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: files
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

NFS server deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: nfs-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: nfs-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nfs-server
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
        ports:
          - name: nfs
            containerPort: 2049
          - name: mountd
            containerPort: 20048
          - name: rpcbind
            containerPort: 111
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /exports
            name: mypvc
      volumes:
        - name: mypvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
```

NFS-server service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
spec:
  ports:
    - name: nfs
      port: 2049
    - name: mountd
      port: 20048
    - name: rpcbind
      port: 111
  selector:
    role: nfs-server
```

Persistent volume and Persistent Volume Claim used by the pods:

```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolume
  metadata:
    name: nfs
  spec:
    capacity:
      storage: 20Gi
    storageClassName: manual
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
    nfs:
      server: 10.4.0.20
      path: "/"

---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

Part of deployment file for pod mounting the nfs

```
      volumes:
        - name: files
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs
```

Output of kubectl get pv and kubectl get pvc

```
user@HP-EliteBook:~/Downloads$ kubectl get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
nfs       100Gi      RWX            Retain           Bound     default/nfs       manual                   286d
nfs-pv    100Gi      RWO            Retain           Bound     default/nfs-pvc   manual                   286d
user@HP-EliteBook:~/Downloads$ kubectl get pvc
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nfs       Bound     nfs       100Gi      RWX            manual         286d
nfs-pvc   Bound     nfs-pv    100Gi      RWO            manual         286d
```

The ip in the PV used by the pods is the problem. The pod on the same cluster can connect to it but not the pod on the other cluster. I can use the actual podIP from the other cluster but the podIP changes with every deploy so that is not a working solution. What is the best way to get around this problem, I only want this second cluster to have access to the nfs server and not opening it to the world for example.

Comment: Question here, based on your deployment manifest, your nfs server is using an nfs persistent volume?

Comment: Yes the nfs-server is also using a persistent volume and volume claim

Comment: Any reason why not just use the same nfs server pv and pvc for the other cluster? What i understood is that u have an external nfs to serve your internal nfs server.

Comment: what about pvc and pv? Can you show the result of "kubectl get pv" and pvc?

Comment: Added some info regarding your comments above. 

@BalChua Not sure how you mean here. How would the pod deployment look for the pod on the second cluster. If I write a claim name there that does not exist on the cluster it wont find it I guess?

Comment: Oh i got what you meant now after posting the manifests.  The closest i can think of is kubernetes federation.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/ or using nodeport at the clusterA (where nfs server is deployed)  but that would open it to the outside world, which is something you want to prevent.